# Terminal gives a "permission denied" error after editing files in Finder

Tags: terminal, finder, permission

When I'm working on a project and using Terminal.app to browse files and run commands, sometimes I need to use Finder to move files into and out of folders, etc. After running such an action, upon my return to the Terminal, attempting to run a command such as 'ls' gives an error:
`ls .: permission denied`.
I can fix this by quitting and reopening Terminal, but it's annoying. Does anyone know why this happens and/or how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the finder have you move the folder where you was positioned in the terminal?

Comment: @Jean_JD yes, I have moved files in or out of folders in the current working directory from the Terminal.

Comment: If you have moved the current directory, you have to do a `cwd "new place"` before other command.

Comment: I haven't... just moving the stuff inside the cwd